# Cannot AOT Akavache.Sqlite3.dll

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, akavache

Fine on debug, but on release I get...

> Error MT3001: Could not AOT the assembly Akavache.Sqlite3.dll'
>   (MT3001) (iOS)

Any ideas? Akavache.Sqlite3 is version 5.0.0.

I found [this](https://github.com/reactiveui/Akavache/issues/81) from five years ago. Not sure what to make of it.

**EDIT:**

In the [docs](https://github.com/reactiveui/Akavache), it  says...

> Handling Xamarin Linker Add the following class anywhere in your
>   project to make sure Akavache.Sqlite3 will not be linked out by
>   Xamarin

```
public static class LinkerPreserve
{
  static LinkerPreserve()
  {
    var persistentName = typeof(SQLitePersistentBlobCache).FullName;
    var encryptedName = typeof(SQLiteEncryptedBlobCache).FullName;
  }
}
```

What is "Linked out"? If I comment out the "encryptedName" line, then it compiles. This makes sense because Akavache doesn't do encryption - so I'm guessing missing encryption code is causing a linker error.

Oh, I take it back. It works with both lines in. No error at all. Although the app crashes on start up.

Comment: what do you mean by not with both lines in?

Comment: for definition of linked out you can see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51070050/what-does-linked-out-by-xamarin-mean

Comment: @albilaga Yes, that’s my question. :)

Comment: @albilaga The word "not" shouldn't have been there. It compiles anyhow - crashes on start up.

Comment: try the alpha version maybe?